# How to create a menu option with HTML in its title from a module?

Tags: routes

HTML in a menu option would be very useful from a module too, i.e. inserting an image as a menu option. Is there a way to do use something like `function MODULE_preprocess_menu_link(&$variables)` inside a module, and not in template.php?

Comment: A partial solution I've found is to declare 
`function theme_menu_item_link($link) { … }`.

Answer (score 3):

Modules can implement preprocess and process functions for theme functions using a template file; for theme functions not using a template file, Drupal 7 allows module to implement a preprocess function.
For example, the mymodule module could implement `mymodule_preprocess_menu_link()` which is a Drupal 7 preprocess function for [`theme_menu_link()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7).

Preprocess and process functions are useful when the variables passed to the theme function need to be changed. If there is the need of changing the output of the theme function, then a module needs to implement [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) and change the function called to serve the output of a theme function.

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['menu_link'])) {
    $theme_registry['menu_link']['function'] = 'theme_mymodule_menu_link';
  }
}
```

With this implementation, `theme_mymodule_menu_link()` would be the function called when a module calls `theme('menu_link', /* … */)`.

#### References

- [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7)

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but sounds legit.

Answer (score 1):

There is contrib module [menu_html](https://drupal.org/project/menu_html) available for adding html to the menu.

If you are trying this in your custom module than you may get some reference from it.